# Video Conference in ASP.NET C# Website

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, video-streaming, video-conferencing

Well, I am developing a virtual classroom i.e. Online classroom, It is a website which provides faculties and students an interactive way of learning. I am almost done just I am stuck with this video conferencing module. I am using ASP.NET C#. I have searched a lot for this. Some information I found is:

1) I got to know about ConferenceXP module. Which is developed by microsoft and enables developers to use it to build their own video-audio conference. I also searched a lot about it, but I am confused on how to implement it in my website. Any suggestion with steps on how to use conferenceXP in website.

2) Though i searched a lot, but yet if some links were left, I am asking this again that Is there any better and easier way( Easier and fast beacuse i need to implement this into my website in 7 days) to implement video-audio chat application in website using C#(Or any other technology working with visual studio).

3) While searching I found something like I can use Skype with my online classroom, Any suggestions related this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [Web RTC/Web Sockets](http://blog.gingertech.net/2012/06/04/video-conferencing-in-html5-webrtc-via-web-sockets/)

Comment: Hey Aron nice find - very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Openmeetings](http://openmeetings.apache.org) from regardless of your technology. The whole interface is SOAP/REST based.